# Making Comments, a sub_menu in admin menu

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

I know this may be a bit crazy, and hopefully there's a way of doing this with out chopping up the core.

I am trying to clean up my Wordpress admin menu's and in doing such I'd like to move Comments under Posts. The problem is obouvisly edit-comments.php is a main menu item and not a sub-menu item.

I know you can make a sub_menu item a main menu item so i hoping to

Visually Speaking it'll look like this.

- Posts

  - All Posts
  - Add New
  - Categories
  - Tags
  - Comments.

I tried this with out luck, which makes sense it doesn't work but it was an attempt...

```
function change_post_menu_label() {
global $menu;
global $submenu;
$menu[5][0] = 'Blog';
$submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Manage Posts';
$submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add New Post';
$submenu['edit.php'][15][0] = 'Categories'; // Change name for categories
$submenu['edit.php'][16][0] = 'Tags'; // Change name for tags
$submenu['edit-comments.php'][25][0] = 'Comments';
$submenu['edit-comments.php'][0][0] = 'Comments';
echo '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way to do it would be to add a new sub menu page and just remove the old one.

```
function wpse_80457_menu() {
add_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'Comments', 'Comments', 'manage_options', 'edit-comments.php'); 
remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
}

add_action('_admin_menu', 'wpse_80457_menu');
```

Answer (score 1):

concur with @Wyck but wanted to add that you can use edit_comment since 3.1 as the capability which seems more appropriate here. Thanks for the easy solution! (not enough reputation to comment ~ sorry)

Comment: You can edit Wyck's answer and include what's new - and then wait for your edit to be approved.

Comment: did not realize I could do that. Thanks for helping me learn.